# How do we select text the Terminal way while inside Vim?

Tags: macos, terminal, vim, terminal.app

For example, when outside of Vim, I can select text then press `cmd`+`c` to copy text. But when I am inside of Vim, I can no longer do that because the mouse interacts with Vim.

Is there some way to get the Terminal selection ability back?

For example, in iTerm, this can be done by holding down the `alt` key, which causes the mouse to stop interacting with Vim, and to highlight text inside the terminal without caring that Vim is running.

Comment: Why not do `:set mouse=all` and then you don't have to worry about whether the mouse is handled by vim or your terminal?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, I'm not sure what do you mean. First of all, `:set mouse=all` results in `E539: Illegal character <l>` for me, but I assume you mean `:set mouse=a`. Then, Vim behaves as @trusktr explains, and he wants to stop that. `:set mouse=` does the trick (as I wrote in my answer).

Comment: @DmitryFrank Ah, that was just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this:

```
:set mouse=
```

And Vim stops handling mouse. If you want Vim to start handling it again:

```
:set mouse=a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac laptop (or have an `fn` key), holding the `fn` key bypasses the active mouse (`:set mouse=a`) in mac terminal, which allows selection.

If you have vim splits or vim within screen/tmux splits it can be funky because you're selecting on the terminal level, not the application level.

A trick in that case is to hold `fn+option`, which at least allows rectangular region selection, which is helpful.

Once a selection is made, `command+c` and `command+v` work as expected, but you may have to hit `i` in vim first to paste, because paste is effectively just typing a bunch of keys into the active application.